# pgfplots - divide y-axis in 2 parts

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a plot, code [here](http://pastebin.com/vgCjTXLG). Now the problem I have is that because of the scale of y-axis it looks as if the plots are actually just 3 lines. Now what I want is that the y-axis is sort of splitted. Into a section ranging from -0.2 to 0.2 and a part ranging from -1.5 to -1.3...

So the y-axis would look like something

```
 0.2 -|
      |
      |
-0.2 -|
      |
-1.3 -|
      |
      |
-1.5 -|
      ----------------------------
```

Is this possible?

-- Okay I see there is a workaround for this using groupplots. But the plot that I give, I was already going to use this inside a groupplot environment with 2 other plots. So can I also use the suggested method in combinations with other normal plots which are combined in a groupplot.

My current setup, now I need the splitting for the third groupplot

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
  width=4cm,
  height=4cm,
  scale only axis,
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  xmajorgrids,
  xminorgrids,
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids
}

\begin{groupplot}[%
  group style={
    group size=3 by 1,
    horizontal sep=50pt,
    vertical sep=40pt
  }
]

\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-0.000196069528802578,
ymax=0.000140838393117182,
ylabel={State error $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'$},
]

\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};

\addplot [
color=green,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};

\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};

\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-3.50920459213846,
ymax=2.98111910953132,
ylabel={$||\delta(t)||/{\delta_0}$}
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};

\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0.5,
xmax=800,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-1.35665432608546,
ymax=0.168623669468375,
ylabel={Lyapunov exponents},
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid,
forget plot
]
};
\addplot [
color=green!50!black,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};
\addplot [
color=red,
solid,
forget plot
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
};

\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}%
```

Let me also note that I need a common y-label, so this solutions to it should be able to work... [Create x and y label which overlaps for multiple plots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117759/create-x-and-y-label-which-overlaps-for-multiple-plots)

Comment: Have a look at [Axis break in pgfplots](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46422/axis-break-in-pgfplots). This might help.

Comment: Could you create a minimal example document that demonstrates your setup?

Comment: @Jake here you go.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion. I use a second `groupplot` environment for the third axis, and place it relative to the second axis. For the `ylabel` I simply used `shift` to move it down a bit. For the third axis, note that the `height` is set explicitly for each of the `groupplots`, so that their combined height is the same as the other axes (4cm).

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,siunitx}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotsset{%
  width=4cm,
  height=4cm,
  scale only axis,
  every x tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  xmajorgrids,
  xminorgrids,
  every y tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize\color{gray!80!black}},
  ymajorgrids,
  yminorgrids
}

\begin{groupplot}[%
  group style={
    group name=first,
    group size=2 by 1,
    horizontal sep=50pt,
    vertical sep=40pt
  }
]

\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-0.000196069528802578,
ymax=0.000140838393117182,
ylabel={State error $\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}'$},
]


\nextgroupplot[
xmin=0,
xmax=800,
xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
ymin=-3.50920459213846,
ymax=2.98111910953132,
ylabel={$||\delta(t)||/{\delta_0}$}
]

\end{groupplot}

\begin{groupplot}[
  group style={
     group name=second,
     group size=1 by 2,
     vertical sep=0pt,
     x descriptions at=edge bottom},
     xmin=0.5,xmax=800,
     anchor=north west]


\nextgroupplot[at={($(first c2r1.outer north east)+(40pt,0)$)},
               ylabel={Lyapunov exponents},
               ylabel style={shift={(-1cm,0)}},
               ymin=-0.3,ymax=0.2,
               axis x line=top, 
               axis y discontinuity=parallel,
               height=2cm]


\nextgroupplot[ymin=-1.5,ymax=-1.28,xlabel={Time [\si{\second}]},
               axis x line=bottom,
               height=2cm]


\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```