# Common x-axis label in different rows of pgfplots mult

Tags: pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to get this effect in my code:

[image]

Bascially I want to move the titles and x-axis label to the center between the two plots in each row.

Can you direct me as to how I can accomplish this?  I have looked at the post [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117759/create-x-and-y-label-which-overlaps-for-multiple-plots) but still can't get the proper output

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
    \usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{float}
    \usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
    \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}

    \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
      Iter   x1   x2      x3      x4      x5      x6
         1, 0.9317521, 1.1849326, 1.6130556, 0.8022207, 0.9317521, 1.1849326
         2, 1.8946202, 1.1228282, 1.8964566, -0.5353802, 1.8946202, 1.1228282
         3, 1.5243302, 1.0372991, 1.4375012, 0.9719003, 1.5243302, 1.0372991
         4, 1.5797030, 1.1346832, 1.8717142, 0.3138737, 1.5797030, 1.1346832
         5, 1.8814457, 1.0529187, 2.0568468, -0.5509391, 1.8814457, 1.0529187
         6, 2.0435003, 1.0470546, 2.0621956, -0.3565483, 2.0435003, 1.0470546
         7, 2.0373926, 1.1215579, 2.1836100, 0.3360301, 2.0373926, 1.1215579
         8, 1.9797077, 1.1632352, 1.8299063, 0.3871091, 1.9797077, 1.1632352
         9, 1.9972528, 1.1952478, 1.8133509, -0.0867033, 1.9972528, 1.1952478
        10, 1.8320176, 1.0625633, 1.0727495, 1.7256738, 1.8320176, 1.0625633
    \end{filecontents*}

    \pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
    \pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \begin{groupplot}[group style={
                                  group size=2 by 3,
                                  vertical sep=2cm,
                                  horizontal sep = 2cm,
                                  ylabels at=edge left},
                                  width=7cm,
                                  height=6cm,
                                  try min ticks=5,
                                  ]
    \nextgroupplot[align =center, title = {\bf{\emph{RSLE Errors}}\\$\mathbf{N(0,1000^2)}$}, xlabel={Number of Recursions}, grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]

    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}
    \coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

    \nextgroupplot[title = {\bf{\emph{MLS Errors}}\\},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};


    \nextgroupplot[title = {$\mathbf{N(0,0.001^2)}$}, xlabel={Number of Recursions}, grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


    \nextgroupplot[grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


    \nextgroupplot[title = {$\mathbf{N(0,0.0001^2)}$}, xlabel={Number of Recursions}, grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


    \nextgroupplot[grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
    \addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


    \coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
    \end{groupplot}

    \path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
              node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large{\bf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}}
              (bot-|current bounding box.west);
    % legend
    \path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
          coordinate(legendpos)
          (bot|-current bounding box.north);
    \matrix[
        matrix of nodes,
        anchor=south,
        draw,
        inner sep=0.2em,
        draw
      ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
      {
        \ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
        \ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]\\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption[Plot showing (a) position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$ and (b)the Parameters Absolute Errors. ]{Plot showing (a) position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$ and (b) the Parameters Absolute Errors.}\label{abserror}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `group name=ape` to the the `group style`, then you can place nodes relative to the corners of the subplots, e.g.

```
\foreach \row in {1,2,3}
  \path (ape c1r\row.south east) --node[below=0.5cm]{Number of recursions} (ape c2r\row.south west);

\path (ape c1r1.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,1000^2)}$} (ape c2r1.north west);
\path (ape c1r2.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,0.001^2)}$} (ape c2r2.north west);
\path (ape c1r3.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,0.0001^2)}$} (ape c2r3.north west);
```

Also, don't use `\bf`, but `{\bfseries bold stuff}` or `\textbf{bold stuff}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10, title/.append style={align =center}}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  Iter   x1   x2  x3  x4  x5  x6
 1, 0.9317521, 1.1849326, 1.6130556, 0.8022207, 0.9317521, 1.1849326
 2, 1.8946202, 1.1228282, 1.8964566, -0.5353802, 1.8946202, 1.1228282
 3, 1.5243302, 1.0372991, 1.4375012, 0.9719003, 1.5243302, 1.0372991
 4, 1.5797030, 1.1346832, 1.8717142, 0.3138737, 1.5797030, 1.1346832
 5, 1.8814457, 1.0529187, 2.0568468, -0.5509391, 1.8814457, 1.0529187
 6, 2.0435003, 1.0470546, 2.0621956, -0.3565483, 2.0435003, 1.0470546
 7, 2.0373926, 1.1215579, 2.1836100, 0.3360301, 2.0373926, 1.1215579
 8, 1.9797077, 1.1632352, 1.8299063, 0.3871091, 1.9797077, 1.1632352
 9, 1.9972528, 1.1952478, 1.8133509, -0.0867033, 1.9972528, 1.1952478
10, 1.8320176, 1.0625633, 1.0727495, 1.7256738, 1.8320176, 1.0625633
\end{filecontents*}

\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dashed,red}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={dotted,green!50!black}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={
  group size=2 by 3,
  vertical sep=2cm,
  horizontal sep = 2cm,
  ylabels at=edge left,group name=ape},
  width=7cm,
  height=6cm,
  try min ticks=5,
  ]
\nextgroupplot[align =center, title={\textbf{\emph{RSLE Errors}}}, grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]

\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot1}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot2}
\coordinate (top) at (rel axis cs:0,1);

\nextgroupplot[title = {\textbf{\emph{MLS Errors}}},grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,red,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};\label{plots:plot3}
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,blue,mark options={scale=.65}]table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma, green, only marks] {data.csv};


\nextgroupplot[ grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=2,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\nextgroupplot[grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=3,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\nextgroupplot[ grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=4,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\nextgroupplot[grid=both, every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.5}]
\addplot [only marks,mark=*,cyan,mark options={scale=.65}] table[x index=0,y index=1,col sep=comma] {data.csv};


\coordinate (bot) at (rel axis cs:1,0);
\end{groupplot}

\foreach \row in {1,2,3}
  \path (ape c1r\row.south east) --node[below=0.5cm]{Number of recursions} (ape c2r\row.south west);

  \path (ape c1r1.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,1000^2)}$} (ape c2r1.north west);
  \path (ape c1r2.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,0.001^2)}$} (ape c2r2.north west);
  \path (ape c1r3.north east) --node[above]{$\mathbf{N(0,0.0001^2)}$} (ape c2r3.north west);

\path (top-|current bounding box.west)--
  node[anchor=south,rotate=90] {\large{\bf{Absolute Parameter Error ($\mid$Estimated - Actual$\mid$})}}
  (bot-|current bounding box.west);
% legend
\path (top|-current bounding box.north)--
  coordinate(legendpos)
  (bot|-current bounding box.north);
\matrix[
matrix of nodes,
anchor=south,
draw,
inner sep=0.2em,
draw
  ]at([yshift=1ex]legendpos)
  {
\ref{plots:plot1}& curve 1&[5pt]
\ref{plots:plot2}& curve2&[5pt]\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Plot showing (a) position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$ and (b)the Parameters Absolute Errors. ]{Plot showing (a) position ${\mathbf{P_{T}}}$ and (b) the Parameters Absolute Errors.}\label{abserror}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```