# Common axis labels pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

Is there a simple way of making a common x-axis label?

I have referred to this:
[Common x-axis label in different rows of pgfplots mult](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276991/common-x-axis-label-in-different-rows-of-pgfplots-mult)

and the solution appears very complex and doesn't work for me.

Here is a my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Work},
ylabel={Effort},
title={Graphpart 1}]
\addplot[no marks]{x^2+x+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Work},
ylabel={Effort},
title={Graphpart 2}]
\addplot[only marks, red, mark size=1pt]{x^3+x+2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this output:
[image: Test_image]

I would like `Work` to be in the centre as the common x-axis label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should use a `groupplot`. But, for now you can use a  slightly *hackish* method and that is to use `xlabel style` to position the `xlabel`:

```
xlabel style = {
    at={(ticklabel cs:0)},
    anchor=north east,
    xshift=-0.35cm,
},
```

A `\vphantom{}` was applied to the first graph's `xlabel` to ensure that the x-axis was located at the same spot vertically.

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{atkinson}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xlabel={\vphantom{Work}},
    ylabel={Effort},
    title={Graphpart 1}]
    \addplot[no marks]{x^2+x+2};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel={Work},
    ylabel={Effort},
    title={Graphpart 2},
    xlabel style = {
        at={(ticklabel cs:0)},
        anchor=north east,
        xshift=-0.35cm,
    },
    ]
    \addplot[only marks, red, mark size=1pt]{x^3+x+2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```